# Test install/uninstall

Tags: graphics, synaptic

I somehow have a nvidia package (possibly nvidia-common) installed on my laptop with ATI, which causes all opengl programs broken with error:

```
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0".
```

Now I want to remove it, but Synaptic will also remove `ubuntu-desktop`. I am afraid I will kill my system.

So this is a more general question: is there a way to test installing/uninstalling a package? And how can I undo it just to be safe.

Comment: this error  is due to the fact that that NX nomachine does not support versions of OpenGL..

Comment: What is NX nomachine? I am not using any remote desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can `test` installation or uninstallation of package through Ubuntu running on `virtual Machine` softwares like `virtualbox`,`VMware`.